# DKIM Record syntax separate symbol

Tags: syntax, editor, vi, dkim

I am trying to add a DKIM Record to my DNS and i noticed that I have to split the entry due to the 250 something character per line limit. I am using Ubuntu 14.

When I split the text do I have to use "**;**" or "**,**" between `v=DKIM1; k=rsa;`?

When I use "**;**" the text after the symbol change color like it is comment in vi editor.

Any clue why this is happening or what I should choose?

Comment: Just to point out that real `vi` does not do colors. Perhaps the tag should be `[vim]` or `[neovim]` or any of the offshoots that do support colour.

Answer (score 0):

If your DKIM exceeds 255 characters you should split it into strings surrounded by double quotes:

```
"v=DKIM1; k=rsa;"

"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA4TWhAkE9cQBB7g2C6jGb
4jdiaShZEtWBkupXFtBdOdJTvrMTAEPIhZske9+bp/ILDYbWG0Tzw7DcmWoTPF+J
bNDH4mN8hSy1pPxyxsmvtFqr5bMlaWl42arkWR3Zzq9A/ReMcEfZ5avwP2JubH72" 

"Bg0SP6NNfrUD9sAWtzOIAt1rT1UygohlB+2EdeHdWFN9neHHDN/hVzL82qufuMZ0
bOAHyn/kuT9hK0HkHc+vHTGIloPlhr6siNfmGwU/Lmv7d7uY/YFpvMvZrl90Fu77
5J7944VNMp6E7tGlJjlt01zDGa5QH1K1funRdrObLxxMgq0Z7RMx5GD5CHMS4tRn
eQIDAQAB"
```

All this should be put into the same TXT record, like so:

```
mail._domainkey.example.com IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA4TWhAkE9cQBB7g2C6jGb4jdiaShZEtWBkupXFtBdOdJTvrMTAEPIhZske9+bp/ILDYbWG0Tzw7DcmWoTPF+JbNDH4mN8hSy1pPxyxsmvtFqr5bMlaWl42arkWR3Zzq9A/ReMcEfZ5avwP2JubH72" "Bg0SP6NNfrUD9sAWtzOIAt1rT1UygohlB+2EdeHdWFN9neHHDN/hVzL82qufuMZ0bOAHyn/kuT9hK0HkHc+vHTGIloPlhr6siNfmGwU/Lmv7d7uY/YFpvMvZrl90Fu775J7944VNMp6E7tGlJjlt01zDGa5QH1K1funRdrObLxxMgq0Z7RMx5GD5CHMS4tRneQIDAQAB"
```

or if you want it split in multiple lines, you can do it with brackets

```
mail._domainkey.example.com IN TXT ("v=DKIM1; k=rsa;"
"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA4TWhAkE9cQBB7g2C6jGb4jdiaShZEtWBkupXFtBdOdJTvrMTAEPIhZske9+bp/ILDYbWG0Tzw7DcmWoTPF+JbNDH4mN8hSy1pPxyxsmvtFqr5bMlaWl42arkWR3Zzq9A/ReMcEfZ5avwP2JubH72"
"Bg0SP6NNfrUD9sAWtzOIAt1rT1UygohlB+2EdeHdWFN9neHHDN/hVzL82qufuMZ0bOAHyn/kuT9hK0HkHc+vHTGIloPlhr6siNfmGwU/Lmv7d7uY/YFpvMvZrl90Fu775J7944VNMp6E7tGlJjlt01zDGa5QH1K1funRdrObLxxMgq0Z7RMx5GD5CHMS4tRneQIDAQAB")
```

Concerning vi, if you're editing your zone files with vi it recognizes that it is a zone file and changes color because `;` is indeed used as a comment character, but it shouldn't color if semicolon is between quotations...

Comment: `vi` doesn't do colours or syntax highlighting. perhaps you are using some other editor based on `vi` (eg. vim, noevim, elvis, etc)?

Comment: @jhnc yes, my bad, I'm using vim